# Error while inserting into partitioned hive table for spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am having hive table with following structure

CREATE TABLE gcganamrswp_work.historical_trend_result(
column_name string,
metric_name string,
current_percentage string,
lower_threshold double,
upper_threshold double,
calc_status string,
final_status string,
support_override string,
dataset_name string,
insert_timestamp string,
appid string,
currentdate string,
indicator map<string,string>)
PARTITIONED BY (
appname string,
year_month int)
STORED AS PARQUET
TBLPROPERTIES ("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY");

I am having spark dataframe with schema

```
root
 |-- metric_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Lower_Threshold: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Upper_Threshold: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Current_Percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Calc_Status: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Final_Status: string (nullable = false)
 |-- support_override: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Dataset_Name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- insert_timestamp: string (nullable = false)
 |-- appId: string (nullable = false)
 |-- currentDate: string (nullable = false)
 |-- indicator: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- appname: string (nullable = false)
 |-- year_month: string (nullable = false)
```

when i try to insert into hive table using below code it is failing

```
    spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    data_df.repartition(1)
      .write.mode("append")
      .format("hive")
      .insertInto(Outputhive_table)
```

Spark Version : Spark 2.4.0

Error:

> ERROR Hive:1987 - Exception when loading partition with parameters
> partPath=hdfs://gcgprod/data/work/hive/historical_trend_result/.hive-staging_hive_2021-09-01_04-34-04_254_8783620706620422928-1/-ext-10000/_temporary/0,
> table=historical_trend_result,  partSpec={appname=, year_month=},
> replace=false,  listBucketingEnabled=false,  isAcid=false,
> hasFollowingStatsTask=false
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> MetaException(message:Partition spec is incorrect. {appname=,
> year_month=})     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartitionInternal(Hive.java:1662)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.lambda$loadDynamicPartitions$4(Hive.java:1970)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> MetaException(message:Partition spec is incorrect. {appname=,
> year_month=})     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.makePartName(Warehouse.java:329)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.makePartPath(Warehouse.java:312)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.genPartPathFromTable(Hive.java:1751)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartitionInternal(Hive.java:1607)

I have specified the partition columns in the last columns of dataframe, so i expect it consider last tow columns as partition columns. I wanted to used the same routine for inserting different tables so i don't want to mention the partition columns explicitly

Comment: maybe because your schema says year_mont int, but dataframe says year_month string?

Answer (score 2):

Just to recap that you are using spark to write data to a hive table with dynamic partitions. So my answer below is based on same, if my understanding is incorrect, please feel free to correct me in comment.

While you have a table that is dynamically partitioned (by app_name and year_month), the spark job doesn't know the partitioning fields in the destination so you will still have to tell your spark job about the partitioning field of the destination table.

Something like this should work

```
data_df.repartition(1)
      .write
      .partitionBy("appname", "year_month")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .saveAsTable(Outputhive_table)
```

Make sure that you enable support for dynamic partitions by executing something like

```
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```

Check out this post by Itai Yaffe, this may be handy https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/spark-dynamic-partition-inserts-part-1-5b66a145974f

Comment: I tried this code. I am getting error message - `partitionBy() can't be used together with DataFrameWriter.insertInto`

Comment: What is the version of spark that you are running ?

Comment: @Arvinth, i have modified my answer for older version of spark, this should work

Comment: I am getting error after trying updated code: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: partition column appname,year_month is not defined in table gcganamrswp_work.historical_trend_result, defined table columns are: column_name, metric_name, current_percentage, lower_threshold, upper_threshold, calc_status, final_status, support_override, dataset_name, insert_timestamp, appid, currentdate, indicator, appname, year_month;`

Comment: @arvinth you are writing to the wrong table.  From your question above, the variable Outputhive_table should be set to gcgcrsnapsd_equifax_t_db.historical_trend_result while from the error message it seems to be set to gcganamrswp_work.historical_trend_result

Comment: I am writing to the same table only. While copy pasting the DDL statement i made a mistake. I am writing to  gcganamrswp_work.historical_trend_result table only

Comment: From the error message it seems like gcganamrswp_work.historical_trend_result is not partitioned by appname, year_month. i would suggest dropping the table and recreating it and ensure that the partitions are reflected correctly.

Comment: I deleted and recreated with proper partition columns but still facing with same issue :(

Comment: Can you please put down your code and your table creation script.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that some records have `appname` and `year_month` as strings. At least this is suggested by

```
Partition spec is incorrect. {appname=, year_month=}
```

Make sure partition colums are never empty or null! Also note that the type of year_month is not consistent between the DataFrame and your schema (string/int)

Comment: I checked the partition columns are not empty or null. Also, i changed the datatype of year_month to int. But still getting same error. Please help